# Trouble upgrading Angular 2 to 4 in npm

Tags: angular

I am having trouble upgrading Angular 2 to 4 in npm. Below is my package.json and I am running npm update --save  in the terminal, however the package.json does not update to the latest Angular 4 and just stays the same. What I am doing wrong?

```
{
  "name": "todo1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.7",
    "@angular/core": "^2.2.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.7",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.7",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.7",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.41",
    "angular2-color-picker": "^1.3.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.28",
    "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^2.7.0",
    "karma": "^1.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "protractor": "^4.0.14",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^1.7.3",
    "tslint": "^4.1.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "webdriver-manager": "^10.3.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-beta.31",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.2.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.38",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.52",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.22-1",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^2.5.0",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "^4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "^1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.0.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3",
    "webdriver-manager": "^10.2.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have updated my app created with angular cli using this tool created by the angular team.

https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: Thanks this is a great tool.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Windows use the following npm command

```
npm install @angular/common@next @angular/compiler@next @angular/compiler-cli@next @angular/core@next @angular/forms@next @angular/http@next @angular/platform-browser@next @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@next @angular/platform-server@next @angular/router@next @angular/animations@next --save
```

Else you can manually update the package.json file with the dependencies and then run npm install

Answer (score 1):

`npm update` doesn't update the [major version](http://semver.org/). This is the first number of the version, it only updates the minor and patch version. Therefor --save doesn't really do much, if you are already on the latest minor version.

You can use the

`npm install @angular/common@latest` ... etc

Or just do a quick search and replace inside your `package.json` for `^2.4.7` to `^4.0.0`. And don't forget to update the router to `^4.0.0` as well, because they aligned the versioning now :)

Comment: Thanks this makes sense why I had the issue :)