# Compilation Angular project fails after upgrading from 2 to 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I have just upgraded my angular project from 2 to 4.
I have done this by:
1-Remove the /node_modules/ folder
2-run:

```
npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest --save
```

In order to add latest versions into package.json

3-run npm install
++here there is already something weird, at the end of the tree i see:
[image]

4- run ng build

The error message i get is:

```
    ERROR in PATH/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.symbol.wellknown.d.ts (133,11): All declarations of 'WeakMap' must have identical type parameters.

ERROR in PATH/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts (124,11): All declarations of 'WeakMap' must have identical type parameters.

ERROR in PATH/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts (45,11): All declarations of 'WeakMap' must have identical type parameters.

ERROR in PATH/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (19417,15): All declarations of 'WeakMap' must have identical type parameters.
```

When i go to one of those above mentioned classes, i see an error message:
 [image]

Saying 'cannot find type object'

My Java background tells me that i am using a compiler that interprets 'object' differently than its used in the library
Indeed i would expect there 'Object' be it a concrete class or interface.
Any advice?

This is my package.json

```
    {
  "name": "rats-gui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/lodash": "ts2.0",
    "angular2-datatable": "0.5.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "2.1.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to close your IDE and run 
 - npm clean cache
 - npm install

Comment: tried: 'npm cache clean' > 'npm install' > 'ng build' still failing

Comment: sorry , i wanna say 
npm cache clear  # to cleaning the npm cache

Comment: can you show me your package.json ?

Comment: I understoon, thank you @ZinebErrahmouni but the issue is still there unfortunatelly

Comment: Hi, sure, i have added it in the post above

Comment: Ok good, did u try to upgrade your npm version ?? 

npm i -g npm

Comment: hey I put this answer on a similar question showing an official guide to upgrade from angular 2 to 4. 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43004329/4113638

hope it helps you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the `"typescript": "^2.3.4"` entry from your `dependencies` and replace the one in your `devDependencies` with `"typescript": "^2.3.4"`. The latest Angluar version requires the typescript version to be at least `2.2.0`.

Couple more things to note:

- move your `@types/lodash` to `devDependencies` and update it to `4.14.66`
- remove the `@angular/compiler-cli` from the dependencies
- replace the `angular-cli` with `"@angular/cli": "1.1.3"`

The last point will probably cause some extra issues, but check the changelog for breaking changes.

Also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43116982/3106920) for more upgrade tips